# Google Developer Console not match instructions for Youtube API setup

Tags: api, youtube

I am trying to find the up to date instructions for creating a google android app credentials does not match the google developer console.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/register

there is no APIs & auth on the sidebar anymore:
In the sidebar on the left, expand **APIs & auth**. Next, click APIs. In the list of APIs, make sure the status is ON for the YouTube Data API v3.

Please advise.
-Tony

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out. I was trying to do it from the Google Play Console rather than from the Google Developer Console. But I first needed to tie my Google Play Console to the Google Developer Console using my settings in my Google Play Console.

-Tony